# iOS Google Ads Interstitial - Get URL

Tags: ios, admob, gadinterstitial

I need to make a deep linking when a google interstitial AD is tapped and checked if the URL is the same as a "known one" to keep the user inside the app rather than opening a WebViewController. I have been trying to get this URL but it seems not possible. There isn't much code to show. I am just looking for someone to point me to the right direction since I haven't found any delegate that passes the URL google will redirect the user to. The initial URL is always the google one.

1. Is there any way to intercept the user tap on the interstitial view controller?
2. Does google pass the URL back to the interstitial view controller?

Comment: can't get exact url to be clicked.. but you can use contentURL for identifying url with similar content as your app . https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6270563?hl=en

Comment: @AmodGokhale thanks a lot but I am not sure that is what I am looking for. I am actually need to know when a url will be redirecting to my own website (www.example.com) and if that is the case, I will keep the user inside my app, in all other cases I will just ket google show other ads websites. I hope it's clear.

Comment: unfortunately its not possible to redirect url... https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/jYkFJ5xubcg ( you might want to ask question to official admob group? )